# Compile less code inside php or html file

Tags: less, phpstorm

Is it possible to put less code inside a php or html file and use some plugin to compile it?

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <style>
         .outerClass {
            .innerClass {
               margin:0; padding: 5px;  // other properties
            }
         }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='outerClass'>
             <div class='innerClass'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just to clarify:

I don't want to use a client or server side compiler. I want to compile before make the deployment, using a plugin for PHPStorm or a script written in NodeJs.

Comment: Client side compilation of Less code is possible but is [not recommended](http://lesscss.org/usage/#browser-support).

Comment: Not client side, but before deployment

Comment: You mean you want to compile a file with Less + HTML and/or PHP code at server side and then deploy the compiled version? Haven't tried anything like that, so have no idea.

Comment: Not. I want to compile with a plugin or a script in NodeJs in my IDE (I use PHPStorm as you can see in the keywords section), before deploy to the server.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible with LESS inside HTML. It only works with standalone files.